# What does 'pose.bones' mean in driver path?

Tags: modifiers, drivers

[image]

I saw the corrective smooth modifier applied to the pants part while looking at the Ellie demo file. The monitor had drivers on it. There, in the path section, it was written as pose.bones["Properties_Character_Ellie"]["Quality"]. But I'm not sure what this means, as I couldn't find any bone named "quality." I even checked the custom properties of the amature but couldn't find anything labeled "quality." Could you please explain what this means?